# Different output using `FullSimplify` and `TargetFunctions`

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

Let's start with this function

```
expr = Abs[((x + a) (y + b)) c]^2
```

with this assumptions

```
$Assumptions={Element[x,Reals], Element[y,Reals] ,a>0,b>0,Element[c,Complexes]};
```

Now something strange happens when I use the TargetFunctions options: If I calculate

```
FullSimplify[(ComplexExpand[
    D[expr, y, x] /.{x -> 0, y -> 0}
    , c, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}]) - (ComplexExpand[
    D[expr, y, x] /.{x -> 0, y -> 0}
    , c])]
```

the output is 0, as I expect.

But if I calculate the same with an extra `FullSimplyfy` I have a different output:

```
FullSimplify[(ComplexExpand[
    D[expr, y, x] /.{x -> 0, y -> 0}
    , c, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}]) - (FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[
     D[expr, y, x] /.{x -> 0, y -> 0}
     , c]])]
```

here the output is

```
-2 a b (-Sqrt[c^2] Abs[c] + Sqrt[c^3 Conjugate[c]])
```

- Why is the last result not zero?
- Why is the output different in the two cases?

Thank you

Comment: Both give `0` for me.

Comment: The second is mathematically also zero because `Sqrt[ c Conjugate[c] ]== Abs[c]`

Comment: This is strange... I'm running Mathematica 11.0.1.0 on Linux (64bit)
I just give, as first input (that means the kernel is clean) the input $Assumptions = {Element[x,Reals], Element[y,Reals], a > 0, b > 0, 
   Element[c,Complexes]};

Abs[((x + a) (y + b)) c]^2;

FullSimplify[(ComplexExpand[
    D[%, y, x]
     /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}
    , c, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}]) - (FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[
     D[%, y, x]
      /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}
     , c]])] and it returns -2 a b (-Sqrt[c^2] Abs[c] + Sqrt[c^3 Conjugate[c]]) not zero...

Comment: I cannot believe this!! If I write the expression with 2 new lines after each semicolon I get the wrong result; if I delete these new lines (I make them just pressing the 'enter' button (the one above the shift button) without any text) I get zero!!! I don't know how to record this behaviour but I should, it's very strange!!!

Comment: @Giancarlo - Question 128818 may have something to do with the semicolon issue.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answers. After I'll read the question mentioned, meanwhile I've uploaded a video of what happens to me

Comment: https://goo.gl/photos/mkRZqm4AG45B9d4A6

Comment: @Giancarlo - Interestingly, with `$Assumptions=True` your second `FullSimplify` call gives 0.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer to the two questions, but may yield some insights.

In SE post #24514 Stephen Kuhn reproduced function PowerContract, originally from the book *Quantum Methods with Mathematica* by James Feagin. Using that function one can get to the desired (zero) output.

```
$Assumptions = {Element[x, Reals], Element[y, Reals], a > 0, b > 0, 
   Element[c, Complexes]};
PowerContract[expr_] := 
 expr //. {m_^q_ n_^q_ :> (m n)^q /; ! IntegerQ[m] && ! IntegerQ[n], 
   m_^q_ n_^p_ :> (m/n)^q /; 
     q >= 0 && p == -q && ! IntegerQ[m] && ! IntegerQ[n]}
expr1 = -2 a b (-Sqrt[c^2] Abs[c] + Sqrt[c^3 Conjugate[c]]);
expr2 = expr1/(-2 a b) (* Get rid of constants *)
(* -Sqrt[c^2] Abs[c]+Sqrt[c^3 Conjugate[c]] *)
expr3 = PowerExpand[expr2]
(* -c Abs[c]+c^(3/2) Sqrt[Conjugate[c]] *)
expr4 = Factor[expr3]/c (* Dividing expr3 by c doesn't help *)
(* -Abs[c]+Sqrt[c] Sqrt[Conjugate[c]] *)
expr5 = PowerContract /@ expr4
(* -Abs[c]+Sqrt[c Conjugate[c]] *)
expr5 // FullSimplify
(* 0 *)
```